# Would spark be a good fit for a budget app?

Tags: apache-spark

Say you have hundreds of thousands of users, and you users are on a daily basis entering their expenses.

So you have lots of users, entering expenses for a specific expense category like:

```
user1  $100.34   category-grocery 2018/01/11
user3  $11.99    category-lunch   2018/01/22
```

On the UI side you display aggregates for expense categories, weekly/daily/monthly budgets etc.

I hope you get the idea.  Would spark be a good fit for this type of application given the aggregate totals etc. have to be in real-time?  i.e once a user enters an expense, it will have to update the appropriate aggregate values.

If yes, would spark streaming be the best approach?

Comment: Assuming the users will only see their own expenses and not others, wouldn't it make more sense to aggregate on the user device than on a server somewhere?

Comment: @Shaido b/c this is a web app not a mobile app.

Comment: I see. No, I don't believe spark would be a good choice for this scenario.